# Selenium button not loading or not clickable

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the page to click on the "Load more" button until it gets to the bottom of the page to extract all data. The button however sometimes doesn't load despite the Selenium's explicit wait or it does appear but not
clickable (I put in print("Load more click") to see if the automation does click and it appears to be doing so -it's just that the button is not clickable). I'm using Selenium 4.1.5 and Chrome driver 104. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, 
ElementClickInterceptedException, NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def ChromeDriver():
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("force-device-scale-factor=1.00")
    options.headless = False
    service = ChromeService("C:\Python39\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    #driver.maximize_window()
    return driver

def toggle_button():
    toggle_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox']")
    toggle_button.click()

def set_currency(currency):
    active_currency = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'modeTitleActive-AXg2YMF0')]").text
    if active_currency!= currency:
        toggle_button()
    else:
        pass

def accept_all():
    try:
        promtpw = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-x59qvYIc']")
        promtpw = promtpw.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='acceptAll-ofWyKNKk button-KXqj4Lf5 size-xsmall-KXqj4Lf5 color-brand-KXqj4Lf5 variant-primary-KXqj4Lf5']").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

def save_as_csv(data_list):
    for idx, data in enumerate(data_list[0:4]):
        file_title = data_list[4][idx]
        file = f"csv/tv_crypto_prices_{file_title}.csv"
        with open(file, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
            tv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            tv_writer.writerow([file_title.upper()])
        data.to_csv(file, mode="a")
    print("csv files saved")

def quit_driver():
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

def get_categories():
    categories = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'item-x59qvYIc')]")
    return categories

def get_categories_list(categories_objs):
    categories_list = []
    for category in categories:
        append_category_text = categories_list.append(category.text)
    return categories_list

def fetch_data():
    data = []
    categories_list = get_categories_list(categories)
    #categories_list = categories_list.append(categories_list.pop(categories_list.index("Overview")))
    accept_all()
    for category in categories:
        category.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        print(category.text)
        
        #Load data
        load_more = True
        while load_more:
            try:
                time.sleep(2)
                load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='tv-load-more__btn']")))
                load_more_button.click()
                print("Load more clicked")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                load_more = False
            except ElementNotInteractableException:
                load_more = False
        
        crypto = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1]
        crypto.columns.values[0] = "Name" #Filter column values
        append_data = data.append(crypto)
    append_categories = data.append(categories_list)
    quit_driver()
    return data

def run_tvc():
    #Get driver
    driver = ChromeDriver()
    driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/")
    
    #Set currency
    currency = "BTC"
    set_currency(currency)
    
    #Get data
    d = fetch_data()
    save_as_csv(d)
run_tvc()
```

I also tried to swap out `load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='tv-load-more__btn']")))` for `load_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='tv-load-more__btn']")` and this seemed to be doing its job for all categories except for the first one ("Overview") where the page first loads along with the url. I would like it to work either ways, in short the problems are:

1. How do you make it work with WebDriverWait where it ends with TimeOutException everytime?
2. Why doesn't the load more button appear for the first category "Overview" with Selenium and how do you fix it? I stopped the process midway and tried reloading the page with the exact same Selenium's Chrome window and the button always appeared and functioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really need selenium? If not so, then the alternative solution is that the required data is also loaded via API.You can grab the entire data from API where method is post and data format is json using `requests` module only.

**Script as example:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
payload = {"filter":[{"left":"market_cap_calc","operation":"nempty"},{"left":"sector","operation":"nempty"},{"left":"name","operation":"match","right":"BTC$"}],"options":{"lang":"en"},"markets":["crypto"],"symbols":{"query":{"types":[]},"tickers":[]},"columns":["base_currency_logoid","sector","market_cap_calc","market_cap_diluted_calc","close","total_shares_outstanding","total_shares_diluted","total_value_traded","change","pricescale","minmov","fractional","minmove2"],"sort":{"sortBy":"market_cap_calc","sortOrder":"desc"},"range":[0,450]}
url= 'https://scanner.tradingview.com/crypto/scan'
headers= {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    }

lst=[]

req=requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=payload).json()

for item in req['data']:
    lst.append({
        "Name":item['d'][1]})


df = pd.DataFrame(lst)#.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)#to store data just uncomment
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                             Name
0                         Bitcoin
1                        Ethereum
2                          Tether
3                        USD Coin
4                    Binance Coin
..                            ...
445                  Tornado Cash
446                      Vertcoin
447                     TokenClub
448                    TrustVerse
449  Atletico De Madrid Fan Token

[450 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Since other categories require clicking to access should I use a webdriver to click on it first to imitate human interaction before requesting for their APIs? For example clicking on performance and then 
`code`perf_payload =[...}
perf_req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=perf_payload).json()`code`
or should you just save all the payload data for all categories and execute the requests with time.sleep in between? Will it increase risk of the IP getting blacklisted in latter case?

Comment: No need to mix and match selenium and API. even not possible to get the required data. You can click manually then go to API  where data is sent  as api url end point